# EWS Managed API: Is it possible to reject the modification of an appointment?

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api

I'm using the notification services to perform several task on the modification of an appointment. Is it possible to reject the modification if certain criteria has been met or do I have to delete the newly created appointment and restore the deleted one?

Comment: Can you provide more information/clarification? Do these appointments have attendees? I think your application gets notifications when there are changes made to appointments in a calendar. There are no ways to moderate changes made to a calendar on the server -- you have to moderate those changes on a client before they are sent to the server. If you don't control all the clients, then you can't moderate those changes. Are you proposing that after an appointment has been changed, and if it meets your criteria, that you restore the deleted version from the recoverable items folder?

Comment: Correct! I don't have any control on the client side, could be a Mobile Outlook Client or something else. So if there isn't any better option i will restore the deleted one.